# How to get the result after each test case instead of logging the results into a file?

Tags: selenium, phpunit

I'm using PHPUnit Selenium.

Is it possible to get the results of the test case in a json format or something and store it into a variable instead of logging it into a file? I don't want to read from a file.

For example, I run the test case testAsdf2. After the test case, i would like to get the results similar to the one below and store it into a variable and insert the results into a database

Is it possible to do that?

```
{"event":"test","suite":"JsonTest","test":"JsonTest::testAsdf2","status":"error","time":10.839267015457,"trace":[],"message":"\nInvalid response while accessing the Selenium Server at 'http:\/\/localhost:4444\/selenium-server\/driver\/': ERROR: Element id=asdfasfe not found","output":""}
```

Comment: Have you read http://phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/logging.html?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to log it into a file. I want to get the results after each test case and store it in a database for each test case instead of reading from a file and getting the data that was just added to the log